# Как захватить все данные?

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Собственно, как захватить все данные ?

Онлайн пример: [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/6axaTR/1/)

Шаблон:

```
(т[^\s]*)\s
```

Текст:

```
    текст  текст
 текст  текст
   текст
```

Comment: Потому что нет `\s` (пробела, перевода строки) после слова.

Comment: @Akina да) как раз этот начал писать в вопросе, т.е. понимаю что его нет. А если делаю `$`, не могу победить жадность(

Comment: `(т[^\s]*)(\s|$)`

Comment: @Deonis спасибо! Как всегда всё просто xD

Comment: `(т[^\s]*)+[\s]{0,}` хотя в примере и так сработает `(т[^\s]+)`

Comment: @PotroNik во, ещё лучше, спасибо. А мне для другого на самом деле,  с `(\s|$)` на примере работает, а в оригинале у меня не работает что то(, а ваш идеально.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В выражении `(т[^\s]*)\s` шаблон `\s` требует наличие пробельного символа после символа `т` и 0 и более непробельных символов. Это значит, что совпадение в конце строки найдено не будет.

Если нужно найти `т` и следующие за этой буквой непробельные символы, используйте

```
т\S*
```

См. [пример работы регулярного выражения](https://regex101.com/r/OJuc24/1) (в POSIX-совместимых средах используйте эквивалентное выражение `т[^[:space:]]*`).

Если перед `т` должен быть пробельный символ или начало строки, используйте

```
(?<!\S)т\S*
```

См. [пример работы регулярного выражения](https://regex101.com/r/OJuc24/2)

Пробельные границы слова выглядят в общем случае так:

```
(?<!\S)текст(?!\S)
```

См. [пример работы регулярного выражения](https://regex101.com/r/OJuc24/3). `(?<!\S)текст(?!\S)` найдёт все совпадения `текст`а между пробельными символами, или в начале или конце строки (блок предварительного просмотра назад `(?<!\S)` требует наличия пробельного символа или начала строки сразу перед первым `т`, а блок предварительного просмотра вперёд `(?!\S)` требует наличия пробельного символа или конца строки сразу после последнего `т`).